# Generate HTML table from SQLdatasource in ASP.net/VB.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, html-table, sqldatasource

I worked on an online web template that has a lot of design classes.

I converted this web template to an **ASPX** file and all is good.
I then created some **SQLdatasource** to read data from a database (using a stored procedure).

after getting the data I need to generate an HTML table with the column name as the `<th>` and the data as `<td>`.

how can I loop through the data returned from the **SQLdatasource** while reading both its header and its corresponding data in **VB.NET**?

the trick is that the amount of data returned from the stored procedure might be changed later so I cannot use `datarow("colomn name").ToString()`, because the column names are not fixed.

using a **gridView** messed up the web page design even after hiding it inside a panel.

Comment: Perhaps you could modify the stored procedure to return the column names as the first row. Does the first row *have* to be filled with `<th>` elements instead of `<td>`? You say you are *not* using a GridView, but you don't say what you *are* using.

Comment: I am using the data source to return the data, then looping on the data to add the <th> , <tr> and <td> tags and the data using DataRowView class